# Open a directory and sort files by date created

Tags: perl, file, sorting

I need to open directories and sort the files by the time they were created. I can find some discussion, using tags for Perl, sorting, and files, on sorting files based on date of modification. I assume this is a more common need than sorting by date of creation. I use Perl. There is some previous postings on sorting by creation date in other languages other than Perl, such as php or java.

For example, I need to do the following:

```
opendir(DIR, $ARGV[0]);                             
my @files = "sort-by-date-created" (readdir(DIR)); 
closedir(DIR);

do things with @files...
```

The CPAN has a page on the sort command, but it's not very accessible to me, and I don't find the words "date" or "creation" on the page.

In response to an edit, I should say I use Mac, OS 10.7. I know that in the Finder, there is a sort by creation date option, so there must be some kind of indication for date of creation somehow attached to files in this system.

In response to an answer, here is another version of the script that attempts to sort the files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

use File::stat; # helps with sorting files by ctime, the inode date that hopefully can serve as creation date

my $usage = "usage: enter name of directory to be scanned for SNP containing lines\n";
die $usage unless @ARGV == 1;

opendir(DIR, $ARGV[0]);                             #open directory for getting file list
#my @files = (readdir(DIR));
my @file_list = grep ! /^\./, readdir DIR; 
closedir(DIR);  

print scalar @file_list."\n";

for my $file (sort {
        my $a_stat = stat($a);
        my $b_stat = stat($b);
        $a_stat->mtime <=> $b_stat->mtime;
    }  @file_list ) {
    say "$file";
}
```

Comment: What operating systems? Many filesystems don't have a creation date, only a modification date.

Comment: Operating system is Mac OS 10.7.

Comment: Why not just use the file test operator? `sort { -C $a <=> -C $b } @files`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can customize the sorting order by providing a subroutine or code block to the [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function.

- In this sub or block, you need to use the special variables `$a` and `$b`, which represent the values from the @array as they are compared.
- The sub or block needs to return a value less than, equal to, or greater than `0` to indicate whether `$a` is less than, equal to, or greater than `$b` (respectively).
- You may use the special comparison operators (`<=>` for numbers, `cmp` for strings) to do this for you.

So the default sort `sort @numbers` is equivalent to `sort {$a <=> $b} @numbers`.

In the case of sorting by creation time, you can use the [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function to get that information about the file. It returns an array of information about the file, some of which may not be applicable to your platform. Last modification time of the file is generally safe, but *creation time is not*. The `ctime` (11th value that it returns) is as close as you can get (it represents inode change time on *nix, creation time on win32), which is expressed as the number of seconds since the epoch, which is convenient because it means you can do a simple numeric sort.

```
my @files = sort {(stat $a)[10] <=> (stat $b)[10]} readdir($dh);
```

I'm not sure if you want to filter out the directories also. If that is the case, you'll probably also want to use `grep`.

Comment: I need to sort by date or time of creation, not by modification time. That seems to be a more common task, but in my case, I need to sort by creation time.

Comment: I don't understand "filter out the directories". What does this mean? To ignore them during a sorting of files?

Comment: By 'filter' I mean to exclude the directories from your list.

Comment: Inode change time is supported in Mac OS X, as is file creation time.  The difficulty is getting at the file creation time in Perl.

Comment: The problem is that some filesystems just don't keep that information

Comment: mtime is index 9, and i found i needed more parens, e.g. ((stat $path/$a))[9]

Answer (score 4):

> I need to open directories and sort the files by the ***time they were created***.

You can't. The *creation time* simply does not exist. There are three time elements tracked by *nix like operating systems:

- **mtime**: This is the time the file was last *modified*.
- **atime**: This is the time the file was last *accessed*.
- **ctime**: This is the time when the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) was last modified.

In Unix, certain file information is stored in the *inode*. This includes the various things you see when you take the Perl `stat` of a file. This is the name of the user, the size of the file, the device it's on, the link count, and ironically, the *mtime*, *atime*, and *ctime* timestamps.

Why no *creation time*? Because how would you define it? What if I move a file? Should there be a new creation time (By the way, *ctime* won't change with a move). What if I copy the file? Should the new copy have a new creation time? What if I did a copy, then deleted the original? What if I edited a file? How about if I changed everything in the file with my edit? Or I edited the file, then renamed it to a completely new name?

Even on Windows that has a *file creation time*, doesn't really track the file creation. It merely tracks when the directory entry was created which is sort of what `ctime` does. And, you can even modify this *creation* time via the Windows API. I suspect that the Mac's file creation time is a relic of the HFS file system, and really doesn't point to a file creation time as much as the time the directory entry was first created.

---

As others have pointed out. You can add into the sort routine a block of code stating how you want something sorted. Here's a quickie example. Note I use [File::stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) which gives me a nice *by name* interface to the old `stat` command. If I used the old *stat* command, I would get an array, and then have to figure out where in the array the item I want is located. Here, the `stat` command gives me a *stat* object, and I can use the `mtime`, `atime`, or `ctime` *method* for pulling out the right time.

I also use the `<=>` which is a comparison operator specifically made for the `sort` command block.

The sort command gives you two items `$a` and `$b`. You use these two items to figure out what you want, adn then use either `<=>` or `cmp` to say whether `$a` is bigger, `$b` is bigger, or they're both the same size.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.0;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my $dir_name = shift;

if ( not defined $dir_name ) {
    die qq(Usage: $0 <directory>);
}

opendir(my $dir_fh, $dir_name);

my @file_list;
while ( my $file = readdir $dir_fh) {
    if ( $file !~ /^\./ ) {
        push @file_list, "$dir_name/$file"
    }
}
closedir $dir_fh;

say scalar @file_list;

for my $file (sort {
        my $a_stat = stat($a);
        my $b_stat = stat($b);
        $a_stat->ctime <=> $b_stat->ctime;
    }  @file_list ) {
    say "$file";
}
```

Comment: About "inode"...So, in the Finder window, when I select to arrange files by "date created," I am really asking the computer to `sort` the files by "ctime", is that correct?

Comment: Also, when you use `use 5.12.0;`, is that to enable the `say` command? Or does `use 5.12.0;` have another or more general purpose here?

Comment: When you use `use 5.12.0` (or above), you enable all the various new features, plus you automatically turn on `strict`. I don't know why warnings isn't also automatically turned on, but it isn't.

Comment: Perl was first written for Unix, so it has a Unix bias. You need to see [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) for these type of _edge cases_. Perlport says on Windows ctime=Win32 creation time, but is silent on MacOS X w/ HFS+. The Mac manpages are little use. There is a MacOSX::File::Info CPAN module that fetches the _creation-date_. Unfortunately, it won't install on my MacBook Pro. If you can use MacOSX::File::Info, you could use that instead of `File::stat` or at least compare `ctime` on `File::stat` to Creation time on MacOSX::File:Info

Comment: Hi, I get this when I try your script lines: Can't call method "mtime" on an undefined value at snpParsing.pl line 29.

Comment: A bit more investigating... I couldn't install MacOSX::File because I am missing Files.h. File.h was a [Carbon header file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-9A581/Files.h), but Carbon is no more. MacOSX::File may no longer be supported. The Mac dev environment has a lot of dross. The HFS+ file system was not written for Unix. HFS+ things like File forks, File Creators, and File Types are on MacOSX, but aren't generally supported and don't have Unix equivalents.

Comment: Hi, so what I meant to say was that I tried your File::Stat and `sort` method that you described up in your first answer. The error message "Can't call method "mtime" on an undefined value at snpParsing.pl line 29." applies to that. Or, is the File::Stat and 'sort` method related to this MacOSX::File method? Are those the same thing? In other words, does your initial answer not work?

Comment: @ES55 - Try cutting out my script as is and trying it on your system. I am using a MacBook Pro with the latest OS X version. It works fine on mine. I can't see what line #29 of your script is, but you must do a `$file_stat_obj = stat($file);` before you can call `$file_stat_obj->mtime`. What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: v 5.12.3.  When I cut and paste, after replacing "." with an actual directory name, I get an error about it not being able to call method "mtime" on an undeclared value. I can paste the code I tried earlier in my question so you can see what line# 29 is about.

Comment: You need to include the directory name when you push the file name into `$file_list`. See my modified program in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

OS X stores the creation date in Mac-specific metadata, so the standard Perl filesystem functions don't know about it. You can use the [MacOSX::File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MacOSX-File/) module to access this information.

Comment: what if i switched over to a PC? What could I do in perl in that case?

Comment: I found that module by googling. I guess you could do the same thing.

Comment: The MacOSX::File module was last updated in 2005.  I just tried installing it on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Perl 5.16.2) and it failed to compile.  A pity...it probably can be fixed, but I've not done so yet.  I use a home-brew version of GCC and a home-built Perl; this may be the problem, but the error message I got was `/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon/strings.h:1:2: warning: #warning Strings.h is not available on Mac OS X [-Wcpp]`.

Comment: Oops. Just checked the blog the pointed me to it, it's from 2002!

Comment: Mac::File depends upon the old Carbon Framework, but Mac OS X no longer supports the Carbon Framework. The Carbon framework was there to help developers port their programs over from the old System 7/8/9 to MacOS X. However, Apple stopped putting supporting it a few OS X releases ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
opendir(DIR, $ARGV[0]);
chdir($ARGV[0]);
my @files = sort { (stat($a))[10] <=> (stat($b))[10] } (readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);
print join("\n",@files);
```

`stat` gives you all kinds of status info for files. field 10 of that is ctime (on filesystems that support it) which is inode change time (not creation time).

Comment: `ctime` is `inode change time`, not `creation time`.

Comment: Also, your arguments to `stat()` are wrong. They should be `$ARGV[0].'/'.$a` and `$ARGV[0].'/'.$b`

Comment: @barman : I've addd chdir to account for that. '/' is not a universal directory separator. and added comment about ctime not being creation time.

Answer (score 0):

[`Mojo::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::File) brings some interesting and readable ways to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojo::File 'path';

my $files_list = path( '/whatever/dir/path/' )->list;

# Returns an array of Mojo::File
my @files = sort { $a->stat->ctime <=> $b->stat->ctime }
  map { $_ }  $files_list->each;

# Returns an array of paths sorted by modification date (if needed)
my @paths = map { $_->realpath->to_string } @files;
```